# How do i render the Array value by comparing another array in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rendering

I have certain array from props which is given below

```
this.props.fruits= [
  {
    source: "Apple",
    code: 101,
  },
  {
    source: "banana",
    code: 105,
  },
  { source: "Mango",
    code: 107,
  },
];
```

in my state I have to save the code only for send it for back-end my state is given below

```
this.state ={
   myfruits:[101,105]
}
```

I have to render the myfruits name in the DOM element
example rendering DOM element

```
My Fruits : Apple , banana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of filter and map method,

```
this.props.fruits.filter((fruit) => this.state.myfruits.includes(fruit.code))
          .map((fruit) => fruit.source)
```

This should solve your problem. You can read more about map and filter [here](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d).

Answer (score 2):

You could make a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get this working.

Example is not React but shows you how this can be achieved.

```js
const fruits = [
  {
    source: "Apple",
    code: 101,
  },
  {
    source: "banana",
    code: 105,
  },
  { source: "Mango",
    code: 107,
  },
];

const state = [101, 105];

const getFruitNames = () => fruits
  .filter(({ code }) => state.includes(code)) // Get all fruit objects where the code is also in state
  .map(({ source }) => source) // Only return the source (name)
  .join(", "); // Turn into a comma seperated string

console.log(`My Fruits: ${getFruitNames()}`);
```

Comment: .join(", ") method is not working while rendering it returns as [object,object].. is there any solution

Comment: @Sanjaikumar It means the items you join are objects. You only need to return the name that you want to show, if you have some more code i can try to debug it.